# Convert PHP foreach loop to Python

Tags: python

My PHP code:

```
$url_array = array();

 foreach($info as $row) {
    $url = $row->url;
    $url_array_2 = explode("/",$url);
    $last_segment = end($url_array_2);

    $url_array[$url][] = $row;

  }
```

Here is Python attempt:

```
 url_array = {};

 for row in info:
     url = row.url
     url_array_2 = url.split("/")
     last_segment = url_array_2[-1]
```

but i get stuck when making the associative array `$url_array[$url][] = $row;`  How do i do this in Python?

Comment: have you looked at `defaultdict`?

Comment: This is not a "translate my code service" please explain what your code is trying to do, at least.

Comment: `{}` is a dictionary, if you want to fill an array or list, you have to use one, not a dict. like `url_array = []`. then appending things to it shouldn't be that hard anymore.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly remeber PHP you can do it without other modules

```
url_array = {}

for row in info:
    url = row.url
    url_array_2 = url.split("/")
    last_segment = url_array_2[-1]

    if url not in url_array:
        url_array[url] = []     # create empty list

    url_array[url].append(row)  # add to list
```

Or you have to use `defaultdict` from standard module `collections`

```
import collections

url_array = collections.defaultdict(list) # create empty list automatically

for row in info:
    url = row.url
    url_array_2 = url.split("/")
    last_segment = url_array_2[-1]

    url_array[url].append(row)
```